# turtlebot navigation using uwb

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone. I am using turtlebot 3 burger with kinetic and ubuntu 16.04. I am using ultra wide band sensor for positioning of robot. I have transmitters and a receiver. The receiver in connected with raspberry pi via usb. I am able make a python code which will calculate the distance from each anchor and give me two readings, i-e x and y. The code runs in pi and not in my PC where i have ros master. Now i want to access this data in ros and use it for naavigation. How can i do that? I am not very experienced in ros, so any help/tutorial will be of great help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332195/turtlebot-navigation-using-uwb/) by [enthusiast.australia](https://answers.ros.org/users/43404/enthusiast.australia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2019-09-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-08**:
@enthusiast.australia: please mark a question as *answered* by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

We don't close questions here when they are answered.

**Comment by [Xiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/49973/xiao/) on 2021-01-19**:
Can you share some information for how to fusion burger and UWB in ros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to set the ros masters Adress as the environment var

export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://yourPcIpl:11311

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2019-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [enthusiast.australia](https://answers.ros.org/users/43404/enthusiast.australia/) on 2019-09-04**:
Where i have to set that? Can you please explain a little what to do and where?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at [Running ROS across multiple machines](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines).
If the pi is in the same network as your PC, you should be able to run ROS on the pi and publish the position to your PC.

---

Originally posted by [danscava](https://answers.ros.org/users/45320/danscava/) with karma: 36 on 2019-09-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [enthusiast.australia](https://answers.ros.org/users/43404/enthusiast.australia/) on 2019-09-04**:
Yes Pi is in same network as my PC but my PC is master and Pi is host. The Pi is in my turtlebot. i run roscore on my PC and master service is started. Now i start my pi with roslaunch bringup command and do my further work. How should i modify things?

**Comment by [danscava](https://answers.ros.org/users/45320/danscava/) on 2019-09-04**:
You should add your PC hostname to the file **/etc/hosts** of your **pi**. Add the following line:

```
192.168.x.x     your-pc-hostname
```

(Fill with the correct information of your PC's hostname and IP.)

In the **/etc/hosts** of your **PC**, add the hostname of the pi

```
192.168.x.x      your-pi-hostname
```

ROS_MASTER_URI is an environment variable that determines where your master is located, in the case of your pi, your master is located on the PC, so this variable on the pi should be:

```
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://your-pc-hostname:11311/
```

To set this variable, you must use the export command in the terminal, like this:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://your-pc-hostname:11311/
```

This is valid only for the current bash, if you want this automatically set every time you run bash, you should add the line above to the file **.bashrc** located on your home folder.